# Is it incorrect to say that a functional "maps functions to numbers"?

Tags: functional-analysis

Does a "functional" always takes in a function and spit out a number?

This is what a professor said in class a long time ago but now I am studying Frechet derivative and a claim was made that a linear functional is $Ax: V \to W$. Can $W$ be anything other than a field i.e. a functional space?

Comment: 1) Yes, functional maps into the underlying scalar field. 2) Yes, for example $W$ can be the space of continuous linear functionals on $V$.

Comment: @user251257: But the dual space of $V$ is also a space consisting of functions :)

Comment: @gerw functional are functions ... I don't get your point.

Comment: @user251257: I think I misunderstood the last sentence in the question.. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

A functional is a map from a vector space $V$ to its underlying scalar field $F$. So not *quite*. For example the norm on $\Bbb{R}^3$ is a functional because it maps the vector $(x,y,z)$ to the real number $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

If you have a function space (a *vector space of functions*), then a *functional* is a map from the vector space (functions) to the scalar field (numbers). For example on $L^1(\Bbb{R})$ the integral which maps $f$ to $\int_{\Bbb{R}} fdx$ is a functional.

A functional can map functions to numbers, and this is the context you'll see it mostly. Or other vectors to other scalars. Functionals defined on exotic vector spaces are still functionals.

Comment: Your example is actually badly defined, you should use $L^1$ or a finite measure subset of $\mathbb{R}$ instead.